# HTML Form: Datalist Option Tag Text Not Change Right To Left

Tags: html, css

How can I change my datalist tag to right-to-left?

```html
<input list="some-list">
<datalist id="some-list">
  <option value="first_value">Some Description</option>
  <option value="another_value">Another Thing Here</option>
  <option value="first_second_third">More Stuff</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask good questions. Your question in it's current state is not very clear. Please add additional information.